# Beautiful Soup code gives unexpected results (edited)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

(The question was edited based on feedback received.  I will continue to edit it based on input received until the issue is resolved)

I am learning Pyhton and beautiful soup in particular and I am doing the Google Exercise on Regex using the set of html files that contains popular baby names for different years (e.g. baby1990.html etc). You can find this dataset if you are interested here: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/baby-names

Each html file contains a table with baby names data that looks like this:

[image]

Before the table with the baby names there is another table.  The html code in the Tags of the two tables is respectively the following

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"> # Unwanted table
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" summary="formatting">  # targeted table
```

You may observe that the targeted differs from the unwanted table by the attribute: summary="formatting"

The first table--the one we must skip -- has the following html code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
  <tr><td class="sstop" valign="bottom" align="left" width="25%">
      Social Security Online
    </td><td valign="bottom" class="titletext">
      <!-- sitetitle -->Popular Baby Names
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#333366"><td colspan="2" height="2"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="graystars" width="25%" valign="top">
       <a href="../OACT/babynames/">Popular Baby Names</a></td><td valign="top"> 
      <a href="http://www.ssa.gov/"><img src="/templateimages/tinylogo.gif"
      width="52" height="47" align="left"
      alt="SSA logo: link to Social Security home page" border="0"></a><a name="content"></a>
      <h1>Popular Names by Birth Year</h1>September 12, 2007</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#333366"><td colspan="2" height="1"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Within the targeted table the code is the following:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" summary="formatting">
<tr valign="top"><td width="25%" class="greycell">
<a href="../OACT/babynames/background.html">Background information</a>
<p><br />
&nbsp; Select another <label for="yob">year of birth</label>?<br />      
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi">
&nbsp; <input type="text" name="year" id="yob" size="4" value="1990">
<input type="hidden" name="top" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="">
&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="   Go  "></form>
</td><td>
<h3 align="center">Popularity in 1990</h3>
<p align="center">
<table width="48%" border="1" bordercolor="#aaabbb"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" summary="Popularity for top 1000">
<tr align="center" valign="bottom">
<th scope="col" width="12%" bgcolor="#efefef">Rank</th>
<th scope="col" width="41%" bgcolor="#99ccff">Male name</th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="pink" width="41%">Female name</th></tr>
<tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>Michael</td><td>Jessica</td> # Targeted row
<tr align="right"><td>2</td><td>Christopher</td><td>Ashley</td> # Targeted row
etc...
```

You can see that the distinctive attribute of the targeted rows is: align = "right".

Now the code to extract the content of the targeted cells is the following:

```
with open("C:/Users/ALEX/MyFiles/JUPYTER NOTEBOOKS/google-python-exercises/babynames/baby1990.html","r") \
as f: soup = bs(f.read(), 'html.parser') 

print soup.tr
print "number of elemenents in the soup:" , len(soup)

right_table = soup.find("table", summary = "formatting")

print(right_table.prettify())

print "right_table" , len(right_table)

print(right_table[0].prettify())

for row in right_table[1].find_all("tr", allign = "right"):

     cells = row.find_all("td")

     try:
                            print "cells[0]: " , cells[0]
     except:
                            print "cells[0] : NaN"
     try:
                            print "cells[1]: " , cells[1]
     except:
                            print "cells[1] : NaN"    
     try:
                            print "cells[2]: " , cells[2]
     except:
                            print "cells[2] : NaN"
```

The output is an error message:

```
    <tr><td align="left" class="sstop" valign="bottom" width="25%">
      Social Security Online
    </td><td class="titletext" valign="bottom">
<!-- sitetitle -->Popular Baby Names
    </td>
</tr>
number of elemenents in the soup: 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-3ec77a65b5ad> in <module>()
      6 right_table = soup.find("table", summary = "formatting")
      7 
----> 8 print(right_table.prettify())
      9 
     10 print "right_table" , len(right_table)

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in prettify(self, encoding, formatter)
   1198     def prettify(self, encoding=None, formatter="minimal"):
   1199         if encoding is None:
-> 1200             return self.decode(True, formatter=formatter)
   1201         else:
   1202             return self.encode(encoding, True, formatter=formatter)

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in decode(self, indent_level, eventual_encoding, formatter)
   1164             indent_contents = None
   1165         contents = self.decode_contents(
-> 1166             indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
   1167 
   1168         if self.hidden:

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in decode_contents(self, indent_level, eventual_encoding, formatter)
   1233             elif isinstance(c, Tag):
   1234                 s.append(c.decode(indent_level, eventual_encoding,
-> 1235                                   formatter))
   1236             if text and indent_level and not self.name == 'pre':
   1237                 text = text.strip()

... last 2 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

C:\users\alex\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in decode(self, indent_level, eventual_encoding, formatter)
   1164             indent_contents = None
   1165         contents = self.decode_contents(
-> 1166             indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
   1167 
   1168         if self.hidden:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The questions are the following:

1. Why the code returns the first table -- the unwanted one-- given that we have passed the argument summary = "formatting"?
2. What the error message implies?  Why it is created?
3. What are other errors you can observe in the code -- if any?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If if had to guess I would say `soup.find` has not found any ocurrence and therefore it has returned `None`. That's why you are getting an error when trying to get the lenght. Look again at the parameters of that function and the file you are working with to see why it's not finding anything.

Comment: And about the text, the random spaces and indentation makes it look pretty messed up. The last part could probably be took together in the form of a list comprehension rather than three differents `Try` `Except`. Also don't use simply `Except`, it may silent some exceptions you don't want to. In the case you can't be more precise about the expected exception use `Except exception as e` and in that block `print(e)´

Comment: @Zanzag Thank you for writing your opinion.  I don't quite understand what you mean when you say that the text is messed up.  I have posted the html code and the code so that you can inspect them and diagnose the problem rather than guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
summary_ = "formatting"
allign_ = "right"
```

delete the `_`, only `class_` has `_`.

> It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but
>   the name of the CSS attribute, “`class`”, is a reserved word in Python.
>   Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of
>   Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword
>   argument `class_`

```
with open('/home/li/Downloads/google-python-exercises/babynames/baby2006.html') as f:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find(summary="Popularity for top 1000")
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        tds = list(tr.stripped_strings)
        print(tds)
```

out:

```
['Rank', 'Male name', 'Female name']
['1', 'Jacob', 'Emily']
['2', 'Michael', 'Emma']
['3', 'Joshua', 'Madison']
['4', 'Ethan', 'Isabella']
['5', 'Matthew', 'Ava']
['6', 'Daniel', 'Abigail']
['7', 'Christopher', 'Olivia']
['8', 'Andrew', 'Hannah']
['9', 'Anthony', 'Sophia']
['10', 'William', 'Samantha']
['11', 'Joseph', 'Elizabeth']
```

Comment: I have edited the code removing the _ as suggested.  The code continues to fail for some reason.  Your opinions and feedback are welcome.

Comment: I did not.  I restored it. Somehow unselects it by itself. The same applies for the previous comment. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes it does! But please explain to me:  Why the value passed to summary is "Popularity for top 1000"?  The html code has summary = "formatting" and the "Popularity for top 1000" appears within <h> tags.

Comment: @im7  to narrow the scope, so that you do not need to worry about the first table in the HTML code, because it's did not exist in the small scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misreading the attribute searching.

If you're looking for 'has summary equal to "Popularity for top 1000"', you should use:

```
soup.find('table', summary="Popularity for top 1000")
```

Hopefully that works for you!